# mysql_fetch_fields returns different length then expected

Tags: mysql, c

I need to create table in other database based on select result types. Query results can map to actual columns in table or not f.e. `Select 1, c from char_length_test`.

How to get actual column size after select statement using mysql C api?

I have created such table:

```
CREATE TABLE char_length_test (c char(22))
```

And using `mysql_real_query` to execute this query

```
SELECT c from char_length_test
```

Right after that I execute `mysql_fetch_fields` to get length of `c` field and expect it to be 22 as in create table statement. Unfortunately length contains value of 66 (3 times more then I expect). Tried different sizes but result is the same, length is always 3 times bigger.

Also used gdb to see if there is any other data field containing expected value:

```
{
name             = "c",
org_name         = "c",
table            = "char_length_test",
org_table        = "char_length_test",
db               = "database",
catalog          = "def",
def              = 0x0,
length           = 66,
max_length       = 0,
name_length      = 1,
org_name_length  = 1,
table_length     = 16,
org_table_length = 16,
db_length        = 6,
catalog_length   = 3,
def_length       = 0,
flags            = 0,
decimals         = 0,
charsetnr        = 33,
type             = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING,
extension        = 0x0
}
```

Comment: Probably the collation used. Length is the number of bytes, so if a collation is used with 3 bytes per character it is triple the declared length of the string. Think mysql defaults to UTF-8 which is 3 bytes per character.

Comment: You probably mean charset? Collation is for sorting. I've tried setting default character set to ascii at the end of create statement, results ar the same. Could it be that mysql uses connection variables to determine this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Charset. Ascii should be a single byte per character (plus any length bytes, etc). Double check that you are not setting the collation though, as that will cause mysql to over ride the default charset for that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_fields() and mysql_field_len() will return a number of bytes required to store a VARCHAR value, not the number of characters. For UTF-8 columns, this will return 3 times the actual column size, even though the documentation says otherwise. This is so that your C code will know how much memory to allocate. If you set your MySQL connection (not the table structure!) to a different character set, you will get different results.

Edit:

You can change the character set of a MySQL connection by calling [mysql_set_character_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-set-character-set.html). If you use an 8bit character set, you should get a number of bytes that matches the width of the database column, e.g.:

```
mysql_set_character_set(&mysql,'latin1');
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Though I still need actual column size, is it possible to get that using C api? Or character size based on character set?

Comment: thanks for pointing a way, I think I'll just divide by 3, since MySQL documentation also states that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Comment: if you put the constant 3 in your code, you should also make sure that your mysql connection actually is utf8 by setting it explicitly. You should also put a comment in the code just in case a future MySQL version supports 4-byte UTF-8 encodings (unlikely, but hey)